# Generate arrays from given strings

Tags: php, arrays

I run the for loop 20 times. Everytime it gets a string from an array("1st", "2nd", "1st", "3rd", "3rd", "1st").

I want to put "1st" string in to the first array. The "2nd" array to another array.
Then I want to put the "1st" string in to the first array! again, since it does match with before created array.

So:
First array contains: "1st", "1st", "1st"
Second array: "2nd"
Third array: "3rd", "3rd"

Is it possible?

Comment: Is "Is it possible?" the Question? The answer is "Yes"!

Comment: `"3th", "3rd"` are the same or just a typo? and why you need loop 20 times if you can easily group different arrays by values?

Comment: Yes it was a typo, sorry. How can I group different arrays by values? :D

Comment: @NeonSmash Why not just keep a count of them ? Why do you store them in an array?

Comment: What's the difference in "just counting them"?

Comment: Why store them as an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a newbie friendly solution. The outer loop goes through the first array of the 1st, etcc.. Then the inner loop goes through the new array and adds the same items to the same array or creates a new array if that item isn't in an existing array.

```js
var arr = new Array("1st", "2nd", "1st", "3th", "3rd", "1st");
var new_arry = [];

for(var x=0;x<arr.length;x++){
  var _val = arr[x];
  if(new_arry.length == 0){
    new_arry[0]= [_val];
  }
  else{
    var create_new_array = true;
    for(var i=0;i<new_arry.length;i++){
        if(new_arry[i].indexOf(_val) > -1){
           create_new_array = false;
           new_arry[i].push(_val);
        }
    }
    if(create_new_array){
        new_arry[new_arry.length] = [_val];
    }
   }
}

console.log(new_arry);
```

Comment: You can just keep a _set_ of values to improve efficiency. You can add this as an alternative approach.

Comment: @vivek_23, I'm not actually sure what you are referring to.

Comment: I would like to see this solution with set of values rather than arrays! I just want them groupped so I can list them later.

Comment: Avoid inner for loop in else condition